# App store connect API not_authorized errors, not deterministic

Tags: api, xmlhttprequest, app-store-connect

I'm trying to retrieve information about the number of downloads of my IOS app via code. For this, I I request the sales reports for specific days, and then I extract the information that I need to get. But for some reason, the first requests (first 8 request more or less) I do, always fail (get an error code: "NOT_AUTHORIZED").

And makes no sense because the tokens and the credentials for the request are constant.

Just to clarify, If I do requests from all the days in February, the first 8 days will give me an error code "NOT_AUTHORIZED". But if I request the days from Genuary and February, the first 8 days will give me the same error, but the 8 days that did fail in the last run, will not in this one.

To clarify it more I did the a similar test as the explained before to show the errors. When output, its just the date, means that there is no error.
[Execution 1, where for this date I get an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGvW7.png)
[Execution 2, the response from the request works correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHWh2.png)

I tried many things and I guess there could be two problems.

1.- My connection isn't good enough, and that's why the request does not work until some time.

2.- For some reason the creation of the credentials or some code is asynchronous, and at the first requests my credentials are not ready.

3.- I have been doing requests some days and maybe, I'm getting 'banned' or 'blocked' for requesting to many times.

Did anyone had any similar error, and may know why is this happening?

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the "*problem ?*".

My connection was not strong enough, I was doing telecommuting, but today, the same program works with no error (I'm in the office).

Even though, I recommend using postman (of some similar software) to check a request first.

At least gives more details about your errors.